# How to align bars in bar chart - Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to align bar to left, but I didn't find anything yet! if there is only one bar its data, then it will render at the center of the chart, and I want to render it on the left!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could add some fake entries into `data.labels`.

```
data: {
  labels: ["A", "", "", ""],
```

Please have a look at below runnable code snippet.

```js
new Chart("chart", {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: ["A", "", "", ""],
    datasets: [{
      label: "My Dataset",
      data: [1],
      backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
      borderColor: "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {    
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: 0,
          max: 1,
          stepSize: 1
        },
        gridLines: {
          drawOnChartArea: false
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          drawOnChartArea: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```css
canvas {
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: bro it's working! but it's a workaround! don't we have anything proper?